# Magento 2: programatically enable/disable Livereload inside theme

Tags: magento2, theme, magento2.2.2, livereload

I've installed livereload and have it working inside of my theme, but there's a problem if I want to use this theme on another server.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/mystyle.css" />
        <script src="http://{myipaddress}:35729/livereload.js" src_type="url"></script>
    </head>
</page>
```

{myipaddress} = the IP address of the server.

How can I programmatically enable/disable livereload and change the IP address based on the server address. I know I can use $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'], but where and how can I insert this logic?

**EDIT**

I've added the following to my default.xml body.

```
<referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
  <block class="Myvendor\Mytheme\Block\Js\Livereload" name="livereload-config" template="Myvendor_Mytheme::js/livereload.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

And then created the corresponding block and template file. Fairly simple, but I just didn't think of it.

Comment: This is not recommended way But I think you can insert `script` in your `header.phtml` template and than where you can make it dynamic IP as per your need.

Comment: You gave me an idea. Maybe I can just add this to a block and insert via layout/default.xml after  body start. I'll try it out